# Draw a polyline by hand in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am creating an Android app that allows user can draw a polyline by hand, I search at quite many sources, but it do not have the method that I need. So do you guys have any idea or some method to solve this?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: A polyline is nothing but an array of coordinates; this cannot be difficult.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I do not know if there is some way that listens from the user change, for example, they draw on some area in the map by a polyline.

Comment: Well, you need at least 2 markers, then you can draw a straight polyline... then just extend with new marker locations. When each verticle is a marker, they can also be dragged & updated. Directions API even has drag-able alternate routes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format